# I want to open vim for git commit but while i write git commit always open nano editor. Thank you

Tags: vim

I want to open vim for git commit but while i write git commit always open nano editor. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To set Another editor just run .

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

To make it persistent add it to `.bashrc` .